Creating Clients the functional way without needing mutable variables
Suppose I want to create 2 clients that extends a base trait
trait Clients {
   def emitter: Emitter
   def push(data: str): Unit
}

case class RestClient(config: RestConfig) extends Clients {
   def emitter: RestEmitter = ??? // where RestEmitter extends Emitter
   def push(data: str): Unit = ???
}

case class KafkaClient(config: KafkaConfig) extends Clients {
   def emitter: KafkaEmitter = ??? // where KafkaEmitter extends Emitter
   def push(data: str): Unit = ???
}

next I have a singleton that returns the caller an instance of the client. Reason I have this singleton is I don't want callers to create multiple instances of the client
object ClientFactory {
   private var client: Option[Emitter] = None // I hate using this mutable state
   
   def getClient: Emitter = {
       if (client.isDefined) client.get
       else throw RuntimeException("client has not init yet")
   }

   def init(config: Config) = {
       config match {
          case rCfg: RestConfig => 
              client = RestClient(rCfg)
          case kCfg: KafkaConfig =>
              client = KafkaClient(kCfg)
       }
   }
}

At startup of the app, I'd initialize using
ClientFactory.init(some_config)

A caller would then use it as
ClientFactory.getClient.push(some_data)

Is there any way of defining this singleton ClientFactory so that I don't have to use this mutable variable

If some of your methods foo requires a Client, then why not just pass it e.g. as def foo(...)(using client: Client), and then instead of writing ClientFactory.getClient, just use client directly? Why would you want to pass it through global mutable state? What you are writing there with the ClientFactory seems like reinvention of untestable dependency injection.

After more than 5 years of professional development, I really really really can't understand why people are so fixated in avoiding passing arguments and in enforcing singletons. - Really, just allow your users to create as many clients as they see fit, and just pass them on the constructors / factories of the classes that need them. Easy to write, easy to test, easy to debug, easy to maintain.

FWIW I like the ZIO approach (ZLayer) for dependency injection in a functional way. macwire can be a simpler approach. Or just do it yourself manually if you only got a couple of classes to inject in others.
